# Kotlin class does not get its boolean value from firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, kotlin, kotlin-android-extensions

I have my kotlin class as

```
class Center : Serializable {
var active: Boolean? = null
var address: String? = null
var isJobAccessGranted: Boolean? = null
}
```

here is how i am getting value

```
 //from java class
   @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            centerMap.put(dataSnapshot.getKey(), dataSnapshot.getValue(Center.class));
        }
```

but problem is that i am getting value of `active` field without any issue. But `isJobAccessGranted` boolean field always remains null. I have tested with some other boolean removing `is` prefix which works fine. I don't get Boolean value when i use `isActive` or `isJobAccessGranted`. Can anyone explain me why i am facing this issue. #AskFirebase

Comment: you have a property called isJobAccessGranted, so appropriate generated getter will be isIsJobAccessGranted. Maybe it is the issue?

Comment: no @mike it is not generating isIsJobAccessGranted

Comment: Dont know the exact reason behind this but using `@field:JvmField` over `var isJobAccessGranted: Boolean? = null` solved my problem

Answer (score 28):

As mentioned in [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46406376/kotlin-class-does-not-get-its-boolean-value-from-firebase#comment79775161_46406376) in `Kotlin` you should add `@field:JvmField` for every `Boolean` field in class, as when `Kotlin` translates to `Java` it generates setters, which names couldnt be resolved by JSON parser. And `@field:JvmField` annotation overrides this feature and there will be correct setters names and JSON will be parsed correctly.

Comment: Why is this not on the front page of the Firebase Kotlin docs ?

Comment: @r3dm4n this is now on the [Firestore docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#custom_objects). Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Sure yes, adding the @field:JvmField resolves it.