# Firestore boolean returns false when its set up to true

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I have a really weird issue, I have run the debugger and step through the code to see each element from Firestore

I have a list of products at my firestore database

Structure

```
shop -> shopId -> products -> productList
```

I have a data class as following

```
@Parcelize
data class Producto(
    val imagenProducto: String = "",
    val nombreProducto: String = "",
    val descProducto: String = "",
    val precio: Int = 0,
    val hasDescuento: Boolean = false,
    val tipoDescuento: Double = 0.0,
    val isCombo: Boolean = false
) : Parcelable
```

And now the code I use to filter by `isCombo` to create two lists that one will contain all the products (with a discount if needed) and combos (if the `isCombo` boolean is set to true)

Now, this is weird, because my code fetches all these documents and sends it to my view

```
suspend fun getProductosList(comercioId:String):Resource<MutableList<Producto>>{
        val productList = mutableListOf<Producto>()
        val snapshot = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("comercios").document(comercioId).collection("products").get().await()
        for(producto in snapshot){
            productList.add(producto.toObject(Producto::class.java))
        }
        return Resource.Success(productList)
    }
```

Here I have a subcollection where the final products of a shop (comercio) are.

### Problem

So, here is what it happens, after I fetch all these documents, the list comes to my view with the data of each element of the list, but one value of the product does not come as espected.

I have place in one document `isCombo = true` but when this comes to my app, it places this value as false but the other boolean `hasDescuento` comes with the right value

### What I have tried

- clean and rebuild
- invalidate cache / restart
- step through with the debugger to see each element see if I was
  inserting my variable with a typo
- check my reference to the data

Here are the outputs, this is how I have the data stored at my reference

[image]

here `isCombo` is set to **true**

Now, this is what ends up in my view when retrieving this document

[image]

So, here `isCombo` comes to false, but my other boolean hasDescuento comes with the right value from the database (for another different product), I was suspecting about the Parcelize annotation in my data class, but all the other data that's not isCombo is fetched normally

What could happen ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems the property with **is** before **Combo** is mapped differently in Firestore and is mapped as just **combo** and not `isCombo`, so, changed the name of the property to `hasCombo`, cleaned and rebuilt the project and it worked.

Thanks to Alex [Firebase Firestore toObject fails on Boolean property mapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52284861/firebase-firestore-toobject-fails-on-boolean-property-mapping)

And will fill a suggestion for the Notes of `boolean` data type at the docs.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/data-types

Comment: I suspect that `isCombo` is being interpreted as a getter for a boolean property named `combo`. Always keep in mind that Firebase/Firestore follows JavaBean patterns for property naming, and this is one of those.

Answer (score 13):

I had the same problem and I found this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52268330/3934111)

```
data class Producto(
    val imagenProducto: String = "",
    val nombreProducto: String = "",
    val descProducto: String = "",
    val precio: Int = 0,
    val hasDescuento: Boolean = false,
    val tipoDescuento: Double = 0.0,
    @field:JvmField // use this annotation if your Boolean field is prefixed with 'is'
    val isCombo: Boolean = false
)
```

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#kotlin+ktx_3

Answer (score 1):

Never, try to use  **isDone, isCombo, isDeclared,...etc** fields (i.e. field must not be prefixed with **is**) , while creating helper Classes, else it will results to Firebase mapping conflicts with your **getters()** and **setters()** methods.

Error might occur at this line:

```
// Here bannerSnapshot is a QueryDocumentSnapshot object
CreateOfferObject product = bannerSnapshot.toObject(CreateOfferObject.class);
```

[**NOTE:**  This error generally occurs in boolean fields.]

I've the same issue, and fixed it just by changing fields name, resetting getter() and setters().

Hope! it helps.